# Missing link in mod message template for low quality

Tags: bug, moderator-tools, moderation, low-quality-posts, moderator-messages

In recent messages [1](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/message/47#47) and [2](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/message/46#46) (sec-mod/staff permissions required), there is a list item with the caption

> Short, self contained compilable examples By Andrew Thompson

It is supposed to be a link to http://sscce.org/, but there is no link.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Information Security mods can, and so the dev team. Think it's good enough. :)

Comment: Confirmed - there was a recent change that causes the link to be stripped out when displaying the message.